# How to resize v-card vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
  <v-card class="pa-8">
   //code
  </v-card>
</template>
```

the code in the browser console displays just one class

```
<div class="v-overlay__content" style="max-width: 600px">
   // my code
</div>
```

I don’t declare the v-overlay__content class itself anywhere, I’m new to Vue

Comment: What's the problem here? You need to understand how the Vuetify components work or you need to resize the `v-card`? The card may be within the overlay, these are internal implementation of the Vuetify components.